# IIS10 UrlRewrite, multiple canonical TLD's & non-canonical sub-domains + HTTPS

Tags: subdomain, dotnetnuke, iis-10, url-rewrite-module, canonicalization

I'm having some trouble with URL rewrite.

I have a website that hosts multiple child sites all within the same Site in IIS10. The primary site has 3 TLD's that should redirect to a primary canonical TLD.

On the same site there are multiple additional bindings for sub-domains of the primary TLD that I don't want redirecting to my primary TLD.

**This is how I'd like to have URL rewrite working:**

**TLD's**

`mydomain.com`

`mydomain2.com`

`mydomain3.com`

--> `mydomain2.com` & `mydomain3.com` should redirect to `mydomain.com` with HTTP to HTTPS.

**Sub Domains**

`c1.mydomain.com`

`c2.mydomain.com`

`c3.mydomain.com`

etc..

--> `c1.mydomain.com`, `c2.mydomain.com`, `c3.mydomain.com`, etc... should NOT redirect to `mydomain.com` with HTTP to HTTPS.

**These are my problematic areas**

If I create a redirect HTTP to HTTPS rule then `mydomain2.com` & `mydomain3.com` don't pull up as my SSL cert is only for mydomain.com and I don't want `mydomain2.com` & `mydomain3.com` as the site's URL, I only want them to redirect to `mydomain.com`

If I don't create a canonical rule then when visiting either `mydomain2.com` or `mydomain3.com` it will fail as there is no matching SSL for those TLD's and the HTTP to HTTPS rule is sending visitors to the HTTPS version a TLD that has not HTTPS binding. Additionally I don't want those URL's staying in the address bar, I want the final domain to be mydomain.com

If I DO create a canonical rule then all my sub-domain bindings will now redirect to `mydomain.com` which is problematic as those are completely different websites being redirected.

I'm using DNN as the CMS so if your familiar with Portals, that's what's happening all child portals are now redirecting to my parent portal and I don't want that.

---

UPDATE per Lex Li's request

**Rules 1) Here is the URL Rewrite rule for redirecting HTTP to HTTPS**

The problem here is that I don't have a canonical redirect to my primary domain.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

**Rules 2) Here is the URL rewrite rules WITH canonical redirect + HTTP to HTTPS**

The problem here is that `subdomain.mysite.com` is redirecting to `mysite.com` where it shouldn't. I see there is a condition's area perhaps there is a way to condition this rule so it doesn't apply to my subdomains?

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Observations:

**Rules 1 Enabled:**

example.com redirects to https://example.com (correct)

example2.com redirects to https://example2.com (fails | no SSL on example2.com & it should redirect to example.com)

sub.example.com redirects to https://sub.example.com (correct)

**Rules 2 Enabled:**

example.com redirects to https://example.com (correct)

example2.com redirects to https://example.com (correct)

sub.example.com redirects to https://example.com (fails, it should redirect to https://sub.example.com)

Comment: Can you edit and show what rules you set right now and what full URL to full URL redirection observed doesn't look good? Only that can make it a question that can be answered, or you'd better hire a consultant to further discuss.

Comment: @LexLi code-behind added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify rule "CanonicalHostNameRule1" to,

```xml
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: so I have bindings that get added in programmatically for `sub.example.com` do I have to add ever sub-domain into this rule or can I use a wildcard like `*.example.com` ?

Comment: I tried `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^*\.example\.com$" negate="true" />` but that didn't work.

Comment: @UserSN please learn a little bit more about regular expression. It should be `^(.*)\.example\.com$`